# Hochschild Cohomology of the Quantum Torus

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, cohomology, noncommutative-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

I would like some advice on how to compute directly, or by a higher powered method the Hochschild Cohomology groups of the quantum torus using the stated complex I have found. I think there are probably much simpler methods of finding the Hochschild Cohomology for this algebra but I am less interested in the in the answer, rather am looking for a method using this specific complex as I want to compute this for a related algebra.

I am very new to homological algebra so if I use strange/incorrect terminology or notation I would be happy to be corrected.

I will set my notation and ask the question.

Let $A$ be the quantum torus (q-not a root of unity): 
$$A:=\mathbb{k}\langle x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1}\rangle/xy-qyx.$$
Note we might want to use the nice basis $A$ inherits from being an Ore extension 
i.e. $A\cong \mathbb{k}[y^{\pm 1}][x^{\pm 1},\alpha]$, where $\alpha(y)=qy$. Thus any element of $A$, say $p$ can be written 
$$p=\sum a_{i,j}x^i y^j.$$

I found the following complex by taking $Hom_{A_e}(.,A)$ of a projective resolution of $A$ I have. In other words the following complex is $Hom_{A_e}(P_{i},A)$ where $P_i$ is a $A^e$ projective resolution of $A$. (Note $A^{\oplus 3}$ means $A\oplus A\oplus A$.)

$$A\rightarrow^{\xi_0} A^{\oplus 3} \rightarrow^{\xi_1} A^{\oplus 4} \rightarrow^{\xi_2} A^{\oplus 4} \rightarrow^{\xi_3} A^{\oplus 4} \rightarrow \ldots$$
(sorry about the poor presentation of the maps)

where the maps $\xi_i$ are defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
&\xi^0(m)=(ym-my,xm-mx,x^{-1}m-mx^{-1}),\\ 
\\
&\xi^1 (m_1,0,0)=(-x m_1+q m_1 x, -x^{-1} m_1+q^{-1} m_1 x^{-1},0,0)\\
&\xi^1 (0,m_2,0)=(q y m_2-m_2 y,0,x^{-1} m_2,m_2 x^{-1})\\
&\xi^1 (0,0,m_3)=(0,q^{-1} y m_3-m_3 y,m_3 x,x m_3 )\\
\\
&\xi^{2j} (m_1,0,0)=(-x^{-1} m_1,-q^{-1}m_1 x^{-1},0,0)\\
&\xi^{2j}(0,m_2,0,0 )=(-q m_2 x,-x m_2,0,0)\\
&\xi^{2j}(0,0,m_3,0)=(ym_3-m_3 y,0,x m_3,-m_3 y)\\
&\xi^{2j}(0,0,0,m_4)=(0,ym_4-m_4 y,-m_4 x,ym_4)\\
\\
&\xi^{2j+1}(m_1,0,0,0)=(-x m_1,q^{-1}m_1 x^{-1} ,0,0)\\
&\xi^{2j+1}(0,m_2,0,0)=(q m_2 x,-x^{-1} m_2 ,0, 0)\\
&\xi^{2j+1}(0,0,m_3,0)=(qym_3-m_3 y,0,0,0)\\
&\xi^{2j+1}(0,0,0,m_4)=(0,q^{-1} y m_4-  m_4 y,0,0).
\end{align*}

At this point I get stuck, I think I want to compute $HH_i(A):=\mathrm{ker} \xi_{i}/\mathrm{im} \xi_{i-1}$ but am a bit stuck on how to do this.

Is this achievable by direct computation for say $HH_1(A)$ or higher?

Are there high powered ways of dealing with this using the information we have?

I am aware that a use of spectral sequences is to simplify homology calculations, could that be used here?

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you mention briefly which projective resolution you are using? Thanks.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I am using a projective resolution which is formed by taking a total complex of a double complex. I haven't actually written out explicitly the total complex before I take Hom. Would it be useful for me to write down the proj res explicitly?

Comment: Well, for learning the subject it is better to understand the first step precisely too. Otherwise, my suggestion for this specific case would be to notice that you can first look at the cosets mod $Im(\xi_k)$ regardless of whether you look at the elements of the kernel or not. For instance, $\xi_{2k+1}$ is very simple on the elements of the form $(0,0,m_3,m_4)$, so this already simplifies the cosets modulo its image, and then you can keep going. Then, after you find easy representatives of cosets, you can see which of those are in the kernel.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Thank you for your suggestion I am trying to use it.

Comment: Am I thinking of this in the right way? We want to find $$HH_1(A):=\mathrm{ker} \xi_{1}/\mathrm{im} \xi_{0}.$$ We know $$\mathrm{ker} \xi_{0}=Z(a),$$ where $Z(A)$ is the centre of $A$ and thus isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}$. We also know $\mathrm{im} \xi_{0}\cong A/\mathbb{K}$, therefore $$HH_1(A):=\mathrm{ker} \xi_{1}/(A/\mathbb{K}).$$ Does this mean $$HH_1(A)\cong \mathbb{K}?$$

Comment: This argument must be false because the same argument could be used for the Weyl algebra which has a trivial centre. But every derivation is inner there, so $HH_1$ would be 0. Again thinking out loud I may very well be mistaken.

Comment: Your notation is a bit messed up. In your post, the target of $\xi_0$ is a free module of rank 3.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Yeah good point how do I reflect that in the notation? Am I OK using the isomorphism theorem to say $\mathrm{im} \xi_0\cong A/\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: The last thing you should be doing is worrying about notation; your idea of using the isomorphism class of the module is confusing (on a simpler example, both $A$ and $Ax$, the left ideal generated by $x$, are isomorphic to $A$ as $A$-modules, but $A/A\not\cong A/Ax$), so just remember what elements it consists of. How did you compute the kernel of $\xi_1$?

Comment: You should take a look at Wambst paper's where he compute small projective resolutions of Quantum planes, and then localize them yo have small resolutions of the Quantum torus